# Новый проект Laravel без Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

создаю новый проект Laravel командой laravel new Project
После этого в папке resources нет папки assets с components и файла app.js 
Что дополнительно нужно установить чтоб отображались компоненты Vue ?

Comment: в случае если у вас установлена версия 5.2 вам следовало бы обновиться на 5.4, так как на версии 5.2 плохая поддержка webpack и vue

Answer (score 2):

Открываем [документацию](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#writing-vue-components) и вуаля

> The Bootstrap and Vue scaffolding provided by Laravel is located in
>   the laravel/ui Composer package, which may be installed using
>   Composer:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

> Once the laravel/ui package has been installed, you may install the
>   frontend scaffolding using the ui Artisan command:

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```